# Can a person be “exaucée”?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, standard

When I look up that word it means to fulfill. However I've seen a sentence where it looks like you can *fulfill* a person. Here is a version of the sentence:

*Une étude des Écritures prouve que Paul a été exaucé.*
(the context being that Paul had been praying)

I haven't been able to find another occurance of the verb being used like this but I've been told by native speakers that it's definitely correct but I've not yet been able to find an explanation online as to why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means indeed that his wishes or prayers were granted.

*Une étude des Écritures prouve que* [les prières de] *Paul* [ont] *a été exaucé*[es].

D'après [le dictionnaire de l'Académie 4<sup>e</sup> édition](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/exaucer) :

> EXAUCER. v.a. Écouter favorablement une prière, & accorder ce qu'on demande. *Dieu exauce les prières des humbles. Le Ciel a exaucé nos vœux.*
>   [alt p. 483] Il se dit aussi Des personnes. *Priez avec ferveur & persévérance, vous serez exaucé. Enfin Dieu nous a exaucés. Dieu a exaucé son peuple,*

Here is an example from the bible,
[Matthieu 6:7](http://www.aelf.org/bible-liturgie/Mt/Evangile-de-Jeesus-Christ-selon-saint-Matthieu/chapitre/6) :

> Lorsque vous priez, ne rabâchez pas comme les païens : ils s’imaginent qu’à force de paroles ils seront exaucés.

Comment: (+1) for this good answer (and also for the hilarious irony of this bible quoting ;-)

Comment: @Romain: You should plainly assume the amused comment. No need to mention upvoting.